# Stack push causes critical error

Tags: c++, stl

I am new to C++ and working with STL container at the moment. 
I got a serious problem executing a `nodeStack.push(startnode)` - the compiler shows up a

> Critical error detected c0000374

Followign code shows the function where the mentioned error occurs:

```
vector<int> Graph::iterativeDepthSearch(map<int, vector<int>> adjlist, int startnode) {
    stack<int> nodeStack;
    vector<int> visitList;

    // Knotenbesuchsliste initialisieren
    int* val = new int(adjlist.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) adjlist.size(); i++) {
        val[i] = 0;
    }

    int cnt = 1;
    nodeStack.push(startnode);
    ....
}
```

The error occurs in the line `nodeStack.push(startnode);`, startnode is initialized with 0.

Comment: totowtwo answer will help you. I would just like to add that for initializing your array a call to ZeroMemory (if available) or memset is sufficient.

Comment: On an unrelated note, did you mean to copy your map into the function rather than use a reference-to-const i.e. `const map<int,vector<int>>&`?

Comment: @hyperboreus or even better, std::fill!

Comment: @totowtwo or even betterer, std::vector.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try `int* val = new int[adjlist.size()];` you are currently allocating a single int and initializing its value, not allocating an array of ints.

The stack structure is corrupting because it is next to your pointer in the memory stack.

Answer (score 4):

nodeStack.push isn't really your problem. You are declaring int* val - a pointer to int, then initializing the integer at val with the size of the list. You really want
    int *val = new int[adjlist.size()];